# JavaScript SetInterval() Queue

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

Is it possible to call a function with `SetInterval()` on specific time but execute the function only once.

```
function get_feed(social) {
  $.ajax({})
}

setInterval(function(){
  get_feed('facebook');
},5000);

setInterval(function(){
  get_feed('twitter');
},10000);
```

I am expecting result to be called only once on the specify time:

```
on 5000ms: get_feed('facebook');
on 10000ms: get_feed('twitter');
```

but currently its calling two functions on 10000ms;

Comment: You need to use `setTimeout` instead.

Comment: What makes you think this is the case?

Comment: I guess, because of this `i am expecting the result to be called only one on the specify time`

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20365971/timing-in-js-multiple-setintervals-running-at-once-and-starting-at-the-same-ti

Comment: @gevorg My addressee wasn't you. I think I have misread the question anyway. I thought OP says the 2 intervals are executed at same time, i.e. the first execution of the first interval happens after 10000ms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm reading you right, you want to get feeds every five seconds and alternate between facebook and twitter. If so, use a single function:

```
var feed = "facebook";
setInterval(function() {
    get_feed(feed);
    feed = feed === "facebook" ? "twitter" : "facebook";
}, 5000);
```

> currently its calling two functions on 10000ms;

That's because your original code schedules `get_feed('facebook')` to run every 5000ms, and `get_feed('twitter')` every 10000ms. So after 5000ms, it does the facebook one, then after anothr 5000ms (10000ms in total), it does both of them, then 5000ms later facebook again, then 5000ms (20000ms in total), both of them...

Comment: hi. id like the function to be called on different time

Comment: @tonoslfx: They are, with the code above. Facebook after 5s, Twitter 5s later, Facebook again 5s later...

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout

```
function get_feed(social) {
  $.ajax({})
}

setTimeout(function(){
  get_feed('facebook');
},5000);

setTimeout(function(){
  get_feed('twitter');
},10000);
```

Comment: how to call the function every 5000 or 10000ms?

Comment: No, `setTimeout` executes for one time only after specified interval. Therefore your solution will just get the feed for facebook and twitter for one time only after 5 and 10 seconds respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function get_feed(social) {
  $.ajax({})
}

var a = setInterval(function(){
  get_feed('facebook');
},5000);

var b = setInterval(function(){
  get_feed('twitter');
},10000);
```

Example:

```js
var p = document.getElementById("text");

var a = setInterval(function(){
    p.innerText = "facebook";
  }, 5000);

var a = setInterval(function(){
    p.innerText = "twitter";
  }, 10000);
```

```html
<p id="text"></p>
```