# Timer count down with React hooks with 2 setTimeInterval approach

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, timer

I'm trying to implement the countdown timer with React's hooks. I knew, we have couple of solutions out there and thanks for that. My question is **NOT** `How to implement timer with React's hooks` **BUT** `What is the problem with my approach`

Here is my code so far.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Timer = () => {
  const [minutes, setMinutes] = useState(29);
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(59);
  useEffect(() => {
    const secondInterval = setInterval(() => {
      setSeconds((prev) => (prev - 1 < 0 ? 59 : prev - 1));
    }, 1000);

    const minuteInterval = setInterval(() => {
      setMinutes(minutes - 1);
    }, 60000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(secondInterval);
      clearInterval(minuteInterval);
    };
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {minutes === 0 && seconds === 0 ? null : (
        <h1>
          {" "}
          {minutes}:{seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : seconds}
        </h1>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Timer;
```

Basically, I just set 2 interval for every render with `useEffect` no depths. But the second `setTimeInterval` does not run and the minutes show `29` everytime.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

When the `useEffect` is called (by setting the seconds for example), your intervals are cleared. This means that the minutes interval is never executed. Add an empty dependencies array to the `useEffect`, and set the `minutes` using an updater function.

However, since your `seconds` and `minutes` are out of sync - the `seconds` starts from 50, and the minutes interval is 60,000 ms (60 sec), you'll only see the `minutes` changing 10 seconds after the `seconds` counter reaches 0.

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

const Timer = () => {
  const [minutes, setMinutes] = useState(29);
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(50);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const secondInterval = setInterval(() => {
      setSeconds(prev => (prev - 1 < 0 ? 59 : prev - 1));
    }, 1000);

    const minuteInterval = setInterval(() => {
      setMinutes(prev => prev - 1);
    }, 60000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(secondInterval);
      clearInterval(minuteInterval);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {minutes === 0 && seconds === 0 ? null : (
        <h1>
          {" "}
          {minutes}:{seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : seconds}
        </h1>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<Timer />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

You can solve this by using a second `useEffect` that sets the `minutes` whenever `seconds` reaches 59:

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

const Timer = () => {
  const [minutes, setMinutes] = useState(29);
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(50);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const secondInterval = setInterval(() => {
      setSeconds(prev => (prev - 1 < 0 ? 59 : prev - 1));
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(secondInterval);
    };
  }, []);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if(seconds === 59) setMinutes(prev => prev - 1);
  }, [seconds]);

  return (
    <div>
      {minutes === 0 && seconds === 0 ? null : (
        <h1>
          {" "}
          {minutes}:{seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : seconds}
        </h1>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<Timer />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this article about [how javascript timers work](https://johnresig.com/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/)

> Since JavaScript can only ever execute one piece of code at a time (due to its single-threaded nature) each of these blocks of code are “blocking” the progress of other asynchronous events. This means that when an asynchronous event occurs (like a mouse click, a timer firing, or an XMLHttpRequest completing) it gets queued up to be executed later

So, as JavaScript is single threaded and can only execute one line at a time, the second `setTimeInterval` for minutes is being blocked by first `setTimeInterval` used for seconds. It is getting queued up to be executed later, and since `useEffect` is being called for every second interval, this queue is getting cleared each time and the code never actually reaches to the second `setTimeInterval`

Comment: I know JS is single thread but `queue up to execute later` does not mean it does not execute at all.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20365971/timing-in-js-multiple-setintervals-running-at-once-and-starting-at-the-same-ti) is similar to this problem. Check it out. Maybe you'll get the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Main issue with your code is missing dependency array. Without dependency array you're adding and removing intervals every render thus your 59 seconds will never happen.

You may want to try console logging like this to make it more clear what is error, just set some variable i globally and log it without dependency array:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const secondInterval = setInterval(() => {
      setSeconds((prev) => (prev - 1 < 0 ? 59 : prev - 1))
    }, 1000)

    const minuteInterval = setInterval(() => {
      setMinutes(minutes - 1)
    }, 60000)
    console.log(i++)
    return () => {
      clearInterval(secondInterval)
      clearInterval(minuteInterval)
    }
  })
```

if you do same thing with dependency array you will see that it actually only prints once which would be desired behaviour.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const secondInterval = setInterval(() => {
      setSeconds((prev) => (prev - 1 < 0 ? 59 : prev - 1))
    }, 1000)

    const minuteInterval = setInterval(() => {
      setMinutes(minutes - 1)
    }, 60000)
    console.log(i++)
    return () => {
      clearInterval(secondInterval)
      clearInterval(minuteInterval)
    }
  }, [])
```

you could potentially add second timer to be 600ms and then only that timer will run as your component will rerender every 600ms.

With empty dependency array your code inside useEffect will only run once, if you wish to include some dependency (for useEffect to run once that value changes just add it to array)